# Is std::this_thread::yield any different from sched_yield on linux?

Tags: c++, linux

I am just wondering how `std::this_thread::yield` is implemented on linux and is it any different from `sched_yield`? I have seen some spinlock implementations that imply `std::this_thread::yield` being something more lightweight that `sched_yield` in terms of for how long the threads abandons the process, is it true?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The implementation of `std::this_thread::yield` in the [libstdc++ library](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/thread#L370) looks like this:

```
    /// yield
    inline void
    yield() noexcept
    {
#ifdef _GLIBCXX_USE_SCHED_YIELD
      __gthread_yield();
#endif
    }
```

The symbol `__gthread_yield` is defined by [in gcc in gthr-posix.h](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libgcc/gthr-posix.h#L691) from which we would need the following:

```
# define __gthrw2(name,name2,type) \
  static __typeof(type) name \
    __attribute__ ((__weakref__(#name2), __copy__ (type))); \
  __gthrw_pragma(weak type)
# define __gthrw_(name) __gthrw_ ## name
...    
/* Typically, __gthrw_foo is a weak reference to symbol foo.  */
#define __gthrw(name) __gthrw2(__gthrw_ ## name,name,name)
...
__gthrw(sched_yield)
...
static inline int
__gthread_yield (void)
{
  return __gthrw_(sched_yield) ();
}
```

So basically in gcc calling `std::this_thread::yield` calls `sched_yield` if `_GLIBCXX_USE_SCHED_YIELD` is defined. You can find if `_GLIBCXX_USE_SCHED_YIELD` is defined in `#include <bits/c++config.h>`, but on linux x86 or x86_64 it most probably is defined. So `std::this_thread::yield` should just call `sched_yield` on a implementation using gcc GNU Compiler Collection and libstdc++ the GNU C++ Library.

In "libc++" C++ Standard Library the `std::this_thread::yield` function definition can be found [in libcxx/thread](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/thread#L410):

```
inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
void yield() _NOEXCEPT {__libcpp_thread_yield();}
```

The symbol `__libcpp_thread_yield` is defined in [libcxx/threading_support](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/__threading_support#L359):

```
void __libcpp_thread_yield()
{
  sched_yield();
}
```

So clang compiler (ie. a compiler that uses libc++ C++ standard library) also calls `sched_yield` on `std::this_thread::yield`.

> I am just wondering how std::this_thread::yield is implemented on linux and is it any different from sched_yield?

Most probably it's the same on most linux implementations.

> I have seen some spinlock implementations that imply std::this_thread::yield being something more lightweight that sched_yield in terms of for how long the threads abandons the process, is it true?

It is most probably false on most linux implementations.

Comment: " So std::this_thread::yield should just call thread_yield" - did you actually mean " So std::this_thread::yield should just call sched_yield"?